# How to get the visible center of a UITable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a standard UITable.  When the user scrolls through the rows and then clicks on one of the cells; they will be transfered to another view.  There will be some process time from the tap of the cell to the new view.  I would like to display a UIActivityIndicator in a view that over lays the center of the UITable.  I am not sure though how to obtain the visible center of the UITable.

The code I have:

```
myView.center = self.tableView.center;
```

Puts it in the center of the UITable until I start scrolling further and further down. Then the UIActivityIndicator stays up at the top, so it appears UITableView.center does not represent the "Visible Center".

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!
Flea

Comment: Personally I think it is preferable to transition to the new view immediately and then show an activity indicator there if it has to do some extra processing before it is ready to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this.

Either you add your activity indicator view to the same view holding the `tableView` and THEN they can have the same center:

```
UIView* superview = [tableView superview];
yourActivityIndicator.center = tableView.center;
[superview addSubview:yourActivityIndicator];
```

or you decide to add your monitor view to the tableView but then the center of this view must be calculated and will depend on the size of indicator view.

```
CGSize tSize = tableView.frame.size;
CGSize aSize  = yourActivityIndicator.frame.size;
yourActivityIndicator.center = CGRectMake(
    (tSize.width-aSize.width)*0.5,
    (tSize.height-aSize.height)*0.5,
    aSize.width,
    aSize.height);
[tableView addSubview:yourActivityIndicator];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the activity indicator in the tableview's parent instead of in the tableview itself, then it won't scroll with the table view